# Efficiently create a matrix from list of named vectors

Tags: r

I want to create a matrix from vectors with names. Where column names are the names of elements, and if some names are not in a vector, a correspondent element will be NA (or 0).

A simple example is something like this:

```
set.seed(1)
vec_a <- rnorm(10)
names(vec_a) <- sample(letters, 10)
vec_b <- rnorm(10)
names(vec_b) <- sample(letters, 10)
vec_c <- rnorm(10)
names(vec_c) <- sample(letters, 10)
vec_d <- rnorm(10)
names(vec_d) <- sample(letters, 10)

example_matrix <- bind_rows(vec_a, vec_b, vec_c, vec_d) 

example_matrix

## # A tibble: 4 x 24
##            y         f          p          c          z          i         a           h
##        <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
## 1 -0.6264538 0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078 -0.8204684 0.4874291  0.73832471
## 2         NA 0.8212212         NA  0.9189774         NA         NA        NA          NA
## 3         NA        NA         NA -0.0593134         NA         NA        NA -0.05380504
## 4         NA        NA         NA         NA -0.7074952  0.7685329 0.3981059          NA
## # ... with 16 more variables: x <dbl>, v <dbl>, m <dbl>, k <dbl>, b <dbl>, g <dbl>, j <dbl>,
## #   l <dbl>, t <dbl>, r <dbl>, q <dbl>, e <dbl>, o <dbl>, u <dbl>, s <dbl>, d <dbl>
```

I know `bind_rows()` works and `example_matrix` is what I want to get.

The problem is this process can be very slow if the vectors get large.

Take another example:

```
all_names <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, 1e4, TRUE), FALSE))
n <- 5e3
vec_a <- rnorm(n)
names(vec_a) <- sample(all_names, n)
vec_b <- rnorm(n)
names(vec_b) <- sample(all_names, n)

tmp <- bind_rows(vec_a, vec_b) # works, but slow
```

This is already slow, and my data are bigger than this (50K unique names, each vector has 10K-30K elements).

I am thinking to make integer indexes of names and construct a sparse matrix directly assigning (i, j, x), but not sure what is the easiest way to construct such indexes.

So the question is what is a method to create this matrix fast? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `rbindlist` function from the `data.table` package. See the example.

```
require(data.table)
require(dplyr)

all_names <- unique(do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, 1e4, TRUE), FALSE)))
anyDuplicated(all_names)
n <- 5e3

vec_a <- rnorm(n)
names(vec_a) <- sample(all_names, n)

vec_b <- rnorm(n)
names(vec_b) <- sample(all_names, n)

length(union(names(vec_a), names(vec_b)))

system.time(tmp1 <- bind_rows(vec_a, vec_b))

system.time(tmp2 <- rbindlist(list(as.list(vec_a), as.list(vec_b)), fill = T))

all.equal(tmp1, tmp2)
```

The output:

```
> system.time(tmp1 <- bind_rows(vec_a, vec_b))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.20    0.00    3.21 

> system.time(tmp2 <- rbindlist(list(as.list(vec_a), as.list(vec_b)), fill = T))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.01 

> all.equal(tmp1, tmp2)
[1] TRUE
```